# Convert string into class name without throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to convert the string into classname using constantize. But it throws error if the classname is not present or the string is empty or `nil`.

Is there any way to convert the string into classname without throwing error. Or returning false only if not able to convert.

Answer (score 5):

I hate Rails, it brings a ton of redundant so-called helpers, having zero value in general. This might be easily done with pure Ruby:

```
Kernel.const_get(string) if Kernel.const_defined?(string)
```

The above effectively returns the class or `nil` (which is falsey in Ruby) if the class is not defined.

Comment: Now hide this in a `String#constantize` and you're one step closer to the dark side :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah. I also always use plain `gsub` for `camelize`, even in Rails projects.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin this will work but rails gives you a way to overcome the `if` here (`safe_constantize`). I gave a +1 to your answer, tho, because this will work for not only a rails project which is really nice!

Comment: @radoAngelov how is `rescue` better than `if`?

Comment: Ah, there is `safe_constantize` in Rails :) I wonder if Rails6 will get `very_safe_constantize` and `safest_constantize_ever`. /cc @SergioTulentsev you should know since you know all about Rails, shed the light, please :-P

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I'm definitely not saying that. It just looks more fancy. I agree with you that if you don't look at the source code of the method you will never know what it is actually doing.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: that is unlikely, this version is safe enough :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin come on now we all know it would be `alias_method :safe_constantize!, :constantize` with documentation that states: *"same as `safe_constantize` but will raise a `NameError` if the constant does not exist."*

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I want to point out something from the answers above. `rescue false` means that all kinds of exceptions thrown from that expression are rescued as false. This means that even if you have an exception object of class `NoMethodError` or `RuntimeError` you will return `false` and your expectation would be that the constantized string does not match a constant in your app. This can cause you hours of debugging if you don't know how the error handling system in ruby is working. It is also a place to introduce a lot of bugs in your code in the future.

I see the **ruby-on-rails** tag so I assume you are running a problem in a rails app. You can use a helper method coming from the `ActiveSupport::Inflector` module. Instead of rescuing the `constantize` method you would probably want to use the `safe_constantize`. It will return `nil` in case the constant is not present in your project.

Example usage (note I haven't defined a `Foo` constant in my project):

```
# with constantize
irb(main) > 'foo'.constantize
=> NameError (wrong constant name foo)

# with safe_contantize 
irb(main) > 'foo'.safe_constantize
=> nil
```

Comment: `safe_constantize` is the correct Rails usage, but I honestly hate Naked String conversions like this. Much better(safer) to  use a "strong params" approach something like:
`allowed_class_names=["Foo","Bar"] 
     
    MyNewClass = string_to_convert.safe_constantize if allowed_class_names.find{|x| string_to_convert == x}
     ...
     etc...
`

Answer (score 0):

What's the error? if it's an exception you can do something like:

```
the_class = your_string.constantize rescue false
```

The `rescue` catches de exception and returns `false` in that case.

Comment: This is most precise answer!

Comment: `rescue false` will not only catch the `NoMethodError` raised from not finding the desired constant - it will catch all types of errors raised from this expression. 

For example `the_class = your_string.method_that_does_not_exist.constantize rescue false` will also return `false` and you can frustrated what is happening here.

Comment: can you check this post too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766842/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-put-for-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a default value or return early in case of `nil` and then rescue a `NameError`:

```
def to_class(name)
   # default to empty string
   (name || "").constantize
rescue NameError
   false 
end 

def to_class(name)
   # guard against invalid input
   return false if name.nil?

   name.constantize
rescue NameError
   false 
end
```

EDIT: It's longer than simple

```
string.constantize rescue false
```

but IMO you should rescue the most specific error you can. `rescue false` is OK for simple scripts or some test cases. In production code it's quite risky - you could hide some exceptions that should be verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by following,

```
string.constantize rescue false
```

**Additional**

If you have have downcase string or table name for that, it can also be converted into class name by using `classify` method as follows,

```
string.classify.constantize rescue false
```

If you have string 'event_managers', it will return class `EventManager`