# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] ) for ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Hope all is well.

I want to ajax call on `_questions_form`. It works without `remote: true` option, yet I am using **actioncable** and when I submit the form my **actioncable** data disappeared upon submitting , so I thought making the form with ajax call to prevent that issue.

my    `_questions_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for complete_tasks_path, :method => :put, :html=>{:remote=>true} do %>
  <ul>
  <% @in_completed_tasks.each do |task| %>
    <li>
      <%= check_box_tag "task_ids[]", task.id %>
      <!--<input type="checkbox" name="task_ids[]" id="task_ids_" value="5">-->
      <%= task.name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit your Answers" if @in_completed_tasks.present? %>
<% end %>
```

my `routes.rb`

```
  resources :tasks do   
    collection do
      put :complete
    end      
  end
```

my `_result.js.erb`

```
 $('#results').html("<%= j (render partial: 'tasks/questions_form') %>")
```

my `task_controller`

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @completed_tasks = Task.complete
        @in_completed_tasks = Task.in_complete
        @answers = Answer.all
    end

    def new
        @task = Task.new
    end

    def create
        @task = Task.create(allowed_tasks_params)
        if @task.save
            flash[:success] =  "Task was saved"
           redirect_to tasks_path
        else
            flash.now[:danger] = "something went wrong"
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def complete

    #  byebug 
    #  Task.where(id: params[:task_ids]).update_all(complete: true)
    #   debugger 
    ids = params[:task_ids]
    if ids
        ids.each do |id|
            answer = Task.where(id: id).first.name
            Answer.create(feedback: answer)
            ActionCable.server.broadcast 'web_notifications_channel',
                                   message:  answer
        end
    end
    #  Task.update_all(["completed_at=?", Time.now], :id => params[:task_ids])
    #   redirect_to root_path

       respond_to do |format|  
            format.js  
        end  
    end


private 
   def allowed_tasks_params
       params.require(:task).permit(:name, :complete)
   end
end
```

my `index.html.erb`

```
<h1>All Questions</h1>
<div id="result">
 <%= render partial: 'tasks/questions_form' %>
</div>

<ul>
<% @completed_tasks.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= c.name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<%= link_to "New Question", new_task_path %> 
<hr/>

<h1>All the answers</h1>
  <div id="messages">  
  </div>
<hr /> 
  <%= pie_chart Answer.group(:feedback).count , suffix: "%", refresh: 60 %>
```

but in console I received such an error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/tasks"):

actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**Note**: Please if more info is needed, ask me to post them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `routes.rb` should generate a routing of

`PUT /tasks/complete` mapped to `TasksController#complete`

but your form is doing a

`PUT /tasks` instead (from your log), so there's something wrong with the request (i.e. your form)

Can you try the following:

```
resources :tasks do   
   collection do
     post :complete
  end      
end

<%= form_tag complete_tasks_path, format: :js, method: :post, remote: true do %>
  <ul>
    <% @in_completed_tasks.each do |task| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag "task_ids[]", task.id %>
        <!--<input type="checkbox" name="task_ids[]" id="task_ids_" value="5">-->
        <%= task.name %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit your Answers" if @in_completed_tasks.present? %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `:method => :put` that you have on your form, if you will create, it needs to be post, but just remove the method part, and it will work.

thats because there is no route to `/tasks` with put method when you create it with `resources`

Comment: now I get this error ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: task):
  
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:48:in `allowed_tasks_params'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:13:in `create'