# Creating a album of medias in Rails. Different Forms for new and edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have on my application a model called Album, that can have multiple media files on it.

This is my model:

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos,dependent: :destroy

  has_many :media
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :media

class Media < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file_name, MediaUploader
  belongs_to :album
end
```

In my views, Im using dropzone so the user can drag and drop medias for his album.

The problem here. When creating a new Album, theres still not an id for it. So, when adding those media with javascript, I got an error because, of course, the belongs_to :album brokes, because we still dont have an album on our app.

So, I want to make one view for the album that, when the user is creating a new album, first it chooses a name and save it. And then he can add medias for this album editing.

The question is, how can I make it DRY as possible? One form that, when creating a new album, only show the NAME attribute. And then, after saving, It can show the Medias drag and drop area?

Comment: You could have a create action that only creates the Album with the name field and then redirect to the edit action for that newly created Album.

Comment: But how can I hide the "medias" div from the create action? Should I create 2 different forms?

Comment: You shouldn't "hide" them since a malicious user could unhide them if that's on the HTML. Just add a new form to create the album with only the name field and a save button, then, on save, `redirect_to edit_album_path(@album)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one form, just display dropzone after if condition

```
<% if form.object.persisted? %>
```

Comment: can you check this post too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766842/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-put-for-ajax-call